# HTML image text is being displayed instead of the image

Tags: javascript, html, list

I currently have some code which takes an array of javascript objects and generates an html list based on it, I want to display the corresponding image with the text in the list. But currently I can only get it to display the address if the image of text. Any help would be appreciated thanks!

HTML

```
<form>
  <p>Please insert the items</p>
  <input type="text" id="box" />
</form>

<div id="root"></div>
```

CSS

```
ul {
    border: 2px solid grey;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 1em;
  }
  li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0.5em;
  }
```

JS

```
const catalog = {

  GalaxyTablet: {
    name: "GalaxyTablet",
    key: "galaxytablet",
    keywords: ["galaxy", "tablet", "samsung"],
    price: 800,
    image: "https://www.jbhifi.co.nz/FileLibrary/ProductResources/Images/150044-M-HI.jpg"
  },
  GalaxyPhone: {
    name: "GalaxyPhone",
    key: "galaxyphone",
    keywords: ["galaxy", "phone", "samsung"],
    price: 1000,
    image: "https://assets.kogan.com/files/product/etail/Samsung-/S10WHT_03.jpg?auto=webp&canvas=753%2C502&fit=bounds&height=502&quality=75&width=753"
  },
  HTCPhone: {
    name: "HTCPhone",
    key: "htcphone",
    keywords: ["htc", "phone"],
    price: 650,
    image: "https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/ca063713e185be46e62ec2eb3762a540.jpg"
},

};

const form = document.querySelector("form");

form.addEventListener("submit", submitHandler);

function submitHandler(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  const searchTerm = form.box.value;
  const results = search(searchTerm);

  render(results);
}

function search(searchTerm) {
  return Object.keys(catalog)
    .filter((key) => catalog[key].keywords.includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase()))
    .map((key) => catalog[key]);
}

function render(results) {
  const root = document.querySelector("#root");
  const list = results.map(itemToLi).join("");

  root.innerHTML = `<ul>
    ${list}
  </ul>`;
}

function itemToLi(item) {
  return `<li>${item.name}</li>$ ${item.price}<li> <li>${item.image}<li>`;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're only getting the URI text because that is what you are outputting:

```
<li>${item.image}<li>
```

You need to create an `img` tag:

```
<li><img src="${item.image}"></li>
```

Here's a small demo with the contents of your catalog:

```js
const catalog = {

  GalaxyTablet: {
    name: "GalaxyTablet",
    key: "galaxytablet",
    keywords: ["galaxy", "tablet", "samsung"],
    price: 800,
    image: "https://www.jbhifi.co.nz/FileLibrary/ProductResources/Images/150044-M-HI.jpg"
  },
  GalaxyPhone: {
    name: "GalaxyPhone",
    key: "galaxyphone",
    keywords: ["galaxy", "phone", "samsung"],
    price: 1000,
    image: "https://assets.kogan.com/files/product/etail/Samsung-/S10WHT_03.jpg?auto=webp&canvas=753%2C502&fit=bounds&height=502&quality=75&width=753"
  },
  HTCPhone: {
    name: "HTCPhone",
    key: "htcphone",
    keywords: ["htc", "phone"],
    price: 650,
    image: "https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/ca063713e185be46e62ec2eb3762a540.jpg"
  }

};

const root = document.querySelector("#root");
const list = Object.values(catalog).map(itemToLi).join("");

root.innerHTML = `<ul>
    ${list}
  </ul>`;


function itemToLi(item) {
  return `<li>${item.name}</li>$ <li>${item.price}</li> <li><img src="${item.image}"></li>`;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [img](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp) tag to render image. Also do not forget to use `alt` attribute inside that.
You can update your existing JavaScript method `itemToLi` as :

```
function itemToLi(item) {
  return `<li>${item.name}</li>$ <li>${item.price}</li> <li><img src="${item.image}" alt=">${item.name}"></li>`;
}
```